# Angular 6 custom pipe to create preview of a paragraph

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe, angular6

So I need to create a pipe that causes a text box to only display the first 150 characters of the description and if its shorter just display the whole description and the preview of the description has to end with (...)

here is where I am at right now

```
 export class TeaserPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    let discTeaser = "";
    if(discTeaser.length >= 150){

    }
    return discTeaser;
  }
}
```

I also don't think I know enough about the custom pipes so any other info would be awesome.

Comment: Why not using CSS for that? Take a look at " text-overflow: ellipsis;"

Comment: Refer this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mk4wzz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fellipsis.pipe.ts

Answer (score 4):

There may be a CSS solution, but if you are serious about a custom pipe, you can try something like this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'truncate'
})
export class TruncatePipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: any, limit: number = 10, trail: string = '...'): string {
        if (value == null) {
             return "";
        }
        return value.length > limit ? value.substring(0, limit) + trail : value;
    }

}
```

In your view, you would want to do something like this:

```
{{ variablegoeshere | truncate : 150 : '...' }}
```